# Postgresql - Like query in JSON field

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql database. i have table with 2 columns(Id, search_term), the search_term is JSON type.

I have data following like this:

Row1:

```
1 - [{"name":"Weight Loss"},{"name":"Hair gain"},{"name":"Loss money"},{"name":"Loss health"}]
```

Row2:

```
2 - [{"name":"Abcd"},{"name":"cmko"},{"name":"Loss money"},{"name":"Loss health"}]
```

Row3:

```
3 - [{"name":"ffuygf"},{"name":"cmko"},{"name":"kooy"} ]
```

Row4:

```
4 - [{"name":"dog"},{"name":"animal"},{"name":"Loss"}]
```

How can i get all matching values with data->>name="Loss".

O/P should be :

```
Row 1,2 and 4.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this-

```
SELECT id, json_string(data,'name') FROM table_name
WHERE json_string(data,'name') LIKE '%Loss%';
```

For more reference [link1](https://gist.github.com/tobyhede/2715918) , [link2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).