# Django JSONField string containment

Tags: django, contains, django-jsonfield

Using Django 1.10's JSONField, i want to filter queryset by the json field that have a value at specific key that contains a sub string (sql like).
e.g. there is a json field `link`, with the `url` key. i want the objects that it's url contains `.jpg`

Comment: No django support afaik, the raw query you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718958/postgresql-like-query-in-json-field

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I will create this with a 'get_queryset' function for the view/model:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        json = params.get('json', None)
        if json is not None:
            """ DO STUFF HERE TO STRIP THE JSON TO THE WANTED LINK """
            q = queryset.filter(json__icontaints=".jpg")
        return q
```

read more about this subject here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

Comment: as specified in official docs, ```contains``` has a special meaning when filtering json field, you used icontains as of normal fields

Comment: This (`json__contains`, `json__icontains`) will not work for JSON fields. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26511